# Compare Date in Vb.net using Datareader

Tags: vb.net

My requiremnet is i want to compare two data values in my database.These two dates belong to two different columns.
What i want to compare is if the date of one column greater by 6 months from the date of other column then it should give error.
I want to pass this query to database and check,and later on depending on the result want to insert my other functionality

Comment: Do you have already these dates or do you need to query them? Where do you have problems with, comparing dates with VB.NET or selecting them via DataReader?

Comment: Actually i have a table in Database.There are two columns with Date datatypes.Its an Library project.The two columns are IssueDate and ReturnDate.
I have to code in my form that if the ReturnDate column is NULL then the corresponding IssueDate should be compared with the current Date of my system and if it is greater or equal to six monthns than it should give an error that not books can be issued.How can i compare in simplest possible way????

Comment: So you don't know how to [query the database with ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx)? Do you need to know if the TimeSpan between the two dates is more/equal than 6 months or does it suffice to know that the difference is (6*30)days?

Comment: strSql1 = "Select * from EmpBooksIssue where EmpCode=" &TxtEmpCode.Text.Trim() & " and DateOfReturn is NULL"
cmd = New SqlCommand(strSql1, con)
If dr.HasRows Then
dr.Read()
dateOfIssue = dr("DateOfIssue")
If dateOfIssue.Compare(currentDate.Date(), dateOfIssue.Date()) >= 6 Then
MessageBox.Show("Book : '" & dr("BookNo").ToString() & "' Not Returned .No further book can be issued")
 End If
 end If

this is what im duin in my code.

Comment: im aware of working with ADO.Netim just having the issue in comparing the date with the current date.
I just want to find out how can i find the difference between the Issued date and the curent Date.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two date objects `ReturnDate` and `IssueDate` and you want to compare them to check if ReturnDate - IssueDate  >= 6 Months:

```
'For this example the two dates are static and not from database':
Dim ReturnDate = Date.Now
If ReturnDate = Nothing Then ReturnDate = Date.Now 'Not initialized, equal to ReturnDate = Date.MinValue
Dim IssueDate = ReturnDate.AddMonths(-6).AddDays(-1) 'more than 6 Months before
Dim halfYearBefore = ReturnDate.AddMonths(-6)
If IssueDate <= halfYearBefore Then
    'this code will actually go here, show error etc.
End If
```

If you have problems to retrieve the date-values from dababase with ADO.NET, have a look at following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx

Comment: Tim thanks mate...m trying the code will get back to u if got some problem..
thanks

Comment: @Ethesham: Consider to [acccept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it works for you, later you also want to upvote answers if they were helpful if you have [enough reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work). Welcome to StackOverflow :)